# React, open from index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple question about React, a JS framework.

How can you start React from index.html after a build.

And not by using `serve -s build` ?

Comment: `index.html` is just an HTML file. You need some sort of server to serve it to your users' browser.

Comment: Well, for our Company, we helping a Customer who provides a remote computer for us to store their solution on. 

We solved it atm by doing a "clean" JS app without any framework. 

But If we were to use a framework, as React, any idea how to proceed?

Comment: How is your customer currently hosting the "clean" JS app? You should only have to give the entire `build` directory to your customer and they should be able to host it in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stephy, I agree with @Tholle, any JavaScript based framework usually is deployed in the server under a web folder as a static bundle of hashed files and assets, which include the Index.html. So, in your case of using React, after you execute: npm build --prod, or something similar, you should get a minified version of your front-end code, which can be deployed in the server. Hope this helps for you!